# scala Regex: Find string between two strings

Tags: regex, scala

I have string like:

```
val str = "$(foo) == 123 AND $(bar) == 321"
```

I want to parse this get: `List(foo, bar)`. What would be the best way to do this?

This is what I tried:

```
val p = """\$\(.*?\)""".r
p.findAllIn(str).toList
```

But the result I get is: `List($(foo), $(bar))`.

How can I get `List(foo, bar)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look-behind with a negated character class:

```
val p = """(?<=\$\()[^()]*""".r
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/wbnEuI)

The `(?<=\$\()` look-behind will make sure we only start matching after a `$(`, and we will match all characters (0 or more) other than `(` and `)` with `[^()]*`.

Comment: I have written a general [article about extracting strings between two strings with regex](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/extracting-text-two-strings-regular-expressions), too, feel free to read if you have a problem approaching your current similar problem.